# Missing the sub Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu with a dropdown. I have created it using the unordered list. I have a second unordered list in the code. I have given both list different class names. The problem is when I put the code together the dropdown menu won't show up. I copied the CSS code from CSS-tricks website and tried to fit it to my project. I am not sure if where I put the class names in the CSS code is right.

```css
    .services {
      columns: 300px 3;
      list-style-position: inside;
      list-style-type: square;
    }

    .services_title {
      color: #000000;
    }

    .services_list {
      background-color: #E6D99C;
      color:#ED3936; 
      padding-left: 150px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      height: auto;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .logo {
      text-align: center;
    }
    h1 {
      color:#ED3936;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul.menu {
      background: #000000;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 325px;
    }

    li.menu_item {
      color: #fff;
      background: #000000;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      padding: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
  
    li.menu_item a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    li.menu_item:hover {
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;    
    }
  
    ul.menu li.menu_item ul.sub_menu {
      background: #000000;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      min-width: 5rem;
      position:absolute;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      left: 0;
      display: none;
      padding: 0;   
    }

    ul.menu li.menu_item:hover > ul.menu,
    ul.menu li.menu ul.menu:hover {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul.sub.menu li.menu_item ul li.menu_item {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Veterinary Services</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Internal Medicine</a></li>
                <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Dental Care</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Boarding</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Grooming</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Customer Portal</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
             </ul>
                                  </li>    
                              </ul>
                       </nav>
                   </head>
               <body>
 
        
            <div class="services_list">
               <h2 class="services_title">Services List</h2>
            
              <p class="services_title">All Pets Vet Hospital is designed to 
               serve four distinct yet overlapping pet care needs. Here is a
              list of all the services we offer.</p>
             <ul class="services">
                <li class="service_item">Allergy testing</li>
                <li class="service_item">Cancer treatment</li>
                <li class="service_item">Cardiology</li>
                <li class="service_item">Dermatology</li>
                <li class="service_item">Diagnostics</li>
                <li class="service_item">Electrocardiography</li>
                <li class="service_item">Emergency/Critical care</li>
                <li class="service_item">End of life care</li>
                <li class="service_item">Endocrinology</li>                 
                <li class="service_item">Endoscopy</li>
                <li class="service_item">Exotic pet care</li>
                <li class="service_item">Eye care</li>
                <li class="service_item">Flea and tick products</li>
                <li class="service_item">In-House laboratory</li>
                <li class="service_item">Intensive care unit</li>
                <li class="service_item">Internal medicine</li>
                <li class="service_item">Laser surgery</li>
                <li class="service_item">Laser therapy</li>    
                    

    <li class="service_item">Laparoscopy</li>                         
                <li class="service_item">Nutrition</li>
                <li class="service_item">Pain management</li>
                <li class="service_item">In-house pharmacy</li>
                <li class="service_item">Puppy/Kitten Care</li>
                <li class="service_item">Radiology</li>
                <li class="service_item">Senior pet care</li>
                <li class="service_item">Spay/Neuter</li>
                <li class="service_item">Surgery</li>
                <li class="service_item">Ultrasound</li>    
                <li class="service_item">Vaccinations</li>    
                <li class="service_item">Wellness</li>    
            </ul>                
           </div>
```

Comment: I would highly suggest using bootstrap and the boostrap navbar instead of writing it yourself.  Not that I don't believe in you, but honestly, navbars cause such headaches when you get into responsiveness and all the different possible states you can account for.  Here is a decent link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: @Thanthu ... which browser? ... with Firefox, I do not see the sub-menu's appearing. The top-level nav items highlight, but that is all that I see.

Comment: Jaipher: do you have a link to where the CSS was copied?

Comment: @Thanthu Actually no, `<ul>` is usually whats used to create menus with dropdown submenus

Comment: I have never heard of bootstrap.  I will definitely look into it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jaipher Bootstrap is a framework - put simply, someone has already set up all the CSS rules and javascript you need to do most website stuff like navbars and lots of other stuff. Just include the bootstrap files and you're ready to go. All you'd need to do above is add the appropriate classes to your nav menu html - you don't have to write a line of css. Take a look at the [examples page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/) to get an idea of what it can do.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I was reading the bootstrap website that I should download bootstrap.  Which is the better option download or us what I think they call BootstrapCDN.  Not sure what the difference is

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking? The difference is that one is downloaded to your own website and one is included directly from BootstrapCDN... Do you mean which is better? It depends on your own setup but both should work. For a live site a CDN is usually better for performance, but based on your inexperience I presume you're not developing industry websites so it doesn't really matter - just give one a go! :)

Comment: One other question, the stylesheet link.  Do I keep the regular link to the CSS stylesheet in the code for the other CSS code or does the bootstrap link work for that too.  When I say regular CSS link I mean this one <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: It depends on what you have in your own style.css. If it only contains the css for to make the nav menu work, then you won't need it. However if it has styles for other elements of your page, or if you want to change the default appearance of the nav bar (e.g. to change the colour for example), then yes you will need your own stylesheet. Make sure you include it *after* the bootstrap stylesheet though, otherwise bootstrap could reset some of your styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I agree with Tyler's comment above - you should consider using bootstrap or similar instead of reinventing the wheel, especially given your inexperience in this area.

To fix the specific issues you mention, the problem is with this selector in your CSS:

```
ul.menu li.menu_item:hover > ul.menu,
ul.menu li.menu ul.menu:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

`ul.menu li.menu_item:hover > ul.menu` is looking for a submenu of class 'menu', but your submenus have class 'sub_menu'. And `ul.menu li.menu ul.menu:hover` will only work when the submenu is hovered over... but its hidden so you can't hover over it!

**How to fix this:**

Instead you can check when the `<a>` link in the main menu is hovered over, and then display the submenu, e.g.:

```
ul.menu li.menu a:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

I've made this change to your code (and removed the extra code that had no effect on ths issue) and you can see it working here:

```css
ul.menu {
  background: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li.menu_item {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000000;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li.menu_item a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.menu_item:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li.menu_item ul.sub_menu {
  background: #000000;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li.menu_item:hover ul.sub_menu,
ul.menu li.menu a:hover {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.sub.menu li.menu_item ul li.menu_item {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Veterinary Services</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Internal Medicine</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Dental Care</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Boarding</a></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Grooming</a></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Customer Portal</a></li>
    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What's the difference between using CSS and using bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code.  I think I understand what you did.  How would I get the menu to be in the center of the page?

Comment: @Jaipher You're using `float:left` which makes it a bit more complicated to center. Have a look through the answers on this question on Stack Overflow - there are a number of solutions there: **[How to centrally align a float:left ul/li navigation menu with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055134/how-to-centrally-align-a-float-left-ul-li-navigation-menu-with-css)**. As you'll see it can get tricky. If you're not very familiar with CSS then you'd really be better off using a framework than re-inventing the wheel.